# Does Bitcoin-Core sanitize all accesses to DataDir?

Tags: bitcoin-core, datadir

I run core in `-disablewallet` mode, but keep my `datadir` on a secondary storage volume, which isn't as secure as my primary drive.  Is this an attack vector?  Could someone stuff some data-bomb in one of the `datadir` files that would serve as a root-kit into my system through bitcoin-core?

Or is the data coming out of `datadir` sanitized against buffer overrun type attacks.  Is `datadir` assumed "trusted" or "untrusted"?

BTW, I always use the `-conf` switch to ensure my `bitcoin.conf` file is secure and housed on a secured volume.